# Android: Why I am not receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED intent?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot, intentfilter

I am testing on an physical device (SAMSUNG ACE GT S5830i)

But I am not receiving the BOOT_COMPLETED intent therefore the service is not Receiver is not starting

This is the code I am using.

```
public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static final String TAG = "InfoService.BroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
    Log.e(TAG, "System boot notification received.");
    Intent service = new Intent(context, InfoService.class);
    context.startService(service);
  } else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Intent received: " + intent);
  }
}
}
```

This is the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.appengine.paranoid_android.lost"
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="1.1">
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".InfoSetup"
              android:label="@string/activity_name"
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".LockScreen"
              android:label="@string/activity_name"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance"
              android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".InfoService"
        android:label="@string/service_name"/>

    <receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/> -->
```

Comment: Your Tag says `InfoService.BroadcastReceiver`. Are you sure your receiver is not a inner class?

Comment: @PankajKumar thank Pankaj, it is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add the full path with the package for `<receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver">`

```
<receiver android:name="com.appengine.paranoid_android.lost.BootCompleteReceiver">
```