# Marshmallow Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, root, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, boot

i have a rotted `Nexus6` With `Android6`. I've created a system app (located in `system/app`) i wish to execute a simple code when receiving ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED but for some reason the code does not executes..

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.atest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.atest.testReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:enabled="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Receiver:

```
public class testReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            // Some simple code
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
When executing with adb the following:

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p com.atest
```

The code execute as expected, but still when rebooting/booting, no success..

Comment: How is it installed in `/system/app`? That's your big clue, your app does not have system level privilege. Install it as normal user instead.

Comment: 1. Does your app really installed? Can you see it in app settings page? Try to search logcat information about your package name. 2. Does this code work on device with Android version less than 6? 3. Before installing as system app, try install it as normal app. Now does the code work?

Comment: @t0mm13b i'm not sure i understand what u mean? what is 'normal user'? and why should i'll get the permissions that way?

Comment: @Daniel 1. Yes. 2. need to check... 3. I've installed it before as a normal app. i didn't got the boot completed permissions. But i checked the same code for USER_PRESENT action and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I am saying, user installed apps do not go into `/system/app` which is system installed applications like google maps etc. All system apps have system privilege and signed by the ROM maker.

Comment: 1. Try open app using launcher activity and reboot. Does your code executed? 2. Try put app in /system/app-priv dir

Comment: @t0mm13b i understand, it's not a system app but a priv-app as Daniel suggested. I've moved it to /system/priv-app and still no success.

Comment: @Daniel regarding (1), the app has been opened before reboot if that is what you mean. Thank you guys both, do you have any other suggestions? i'm still stuck...

Comment: Name of receiver shouldn't be .testReceiver? Why is it com.atest.testReceiver?

Comment: I've tried to change it because f this thrad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691806/android-why-i-am-not-receiving-the-boot-completed-intent
But it's the same result neither way

Comment: Oh i found something interesting, i'll edit the question maybe it will help to figure this out..

Comment: @Daniel also tried on Android 4.4.2 (also rooted, in priv-app and all). Result is the same.. i guess i'm missing something. Don't know what, probably a really basic one...!

Comment: You have looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051687/broadcastreceiver-not-receiving-boot-completed) Try changing installLocation to internal, or add a category?

Comment: Usually you don't need to use. "-p" switch in order to test your receiver. If you omit it, does it work?

Comment: @t0mm13b tried it just now.. no success.

Comment: @Daniel without "-p" device will reboot..